# How can I convert this INT field to a usable date field?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, type-conversion

The DB I am working in stores their date values as `INT`.  I am needing to determine a date difference between two `date` fields but am unsure how to approach this since they are currently `INT`.

Dates are stored as follows: `20130101` - `YYYYDDMM`.  Performing a DATEDIFF results in an arithmetic overflow error.

Any ideas on how to either convert two `date` fields or to find the date difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Cast( Cast( 20130101 As varchar(8) ) As datetime )
```

So, if you have the following two values: `20130101`, `20130201`, we might do the following:

```
Select DateDiff( d
    , Cast( Cast( 20130101 As varchar(8) ) As datetime )
    , Cast( Cast( 20130201 As varchar(8) ) As datetime ) )
```

#### Update

If you have values that less than `17530101` (the min value for a datetime), then you will need to use a Case expression to validate the data as it is processed. In this scenario, the use of `Cast(0 As datetime)` will result in `1900-01-01` as our minimum date value.

```
Select DateDiff( d
    , Case
        When Value1 <= 19000101 Then Cast(0 As datetime)
        Else Cast( Cast( Value1 As varchar(8) ) As datetime )
        End
    , Case
        When Value2 <= 19000101 Then Cast(0 As datetime)
        Else Cast( Cast( Value2 As varchar(8) ) As datetime )
        End )
```

If you are going to store the dates as integers as shown, a better idea would be to correct the data and add a check constraint that prevents values lower than `1900-01-01`. If you have legitimate values lower than `1900-01-01`, that will require yet another adjustment to the solution.

Comment: When I tried the above DateDiff code, I found that for one of the fields, type INT, the conversion was successful; however, for the other field, same data type, I receive the 'Conversion failed when converting datetime to character string' message.

Comment: I am wondering if this could be due to the fact that, for the field currently in error, there are numerous values of 0 present in the data; whereas, for the correctly working field conversion, all of the values contain a date.

Comment: Could you post the code you used, and the values of the columns? The code above doesn't try to convert a datetime to a string.

Comment: Oh, the message probably says "from" rather than "to".  Yes, that would fail. You need to either filter those (0 value) rows out, or decide how you want to handle 0 values (which you could do with a CASE expression).

Comment: @Gryphoenix - What date value should a 0 represent? 19000101? Obviously, one solution would be to add and enforce a check constraint that prevents earlier than 19000101 from being entered into this column. Barring that, you'll have to use Case expressions. Will update my post to illustrate.

Comment: @GilM - that makes sense and I can definitely filter out those values.

Comment: @Thomas - that I am not sure of.  Working in a Legacy MRP system with limited knowledge of its inner workings.  At this point, finding the date difference for non-zero values meets my needs.  Thank you for your help!